Is there any way to cancel initialize object class if there is an error occurs in Python?
class EntityRetrieval(object):
    
    def __init__(self,
                 entity_kb_path: str):
        
        """
        Args
            entity_kb_path: path of entity knowledge base (string) which is json format
        """
        
        try:        
            entity_kb = json.load(open(entity_kb_path,'r'))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            
        # Don't use entity type 
        entity_dict = {}
        
        for entity_type, entities in entity_kb.items():
            for entity_id, list_entity_strings in entities.items():
                entity_dict[entity_id] = list_entity_strings


Above is my ugly code. Here is what I concern:

Does it really need to catch error to prevent crashing? In the above code, the entity_kb_path has to be json file. There might be incorrect format file error, not found file error. And I try to throw message error to user when they not pass in correct argument instead of throw crash.
But when I use try catch, the initialization still running and return an instance, I think this is not logical, I mean it should stop initalizing right?
If try except puts there then there something weird that the entity_kb variable might not be declared. But the process block code behind that is too long. I might not want to put it in the try block

So how do you do in those scenarios?


Does it really need to catch error to prevent crashing?

If you are not handling the Exception in any part of the code, the code will surely crash.
I think you can let the user of your class (e.g., you) decide whether to make the code crash or handle the exception differently like for instance change the path.
Example code of your class:
class EntityRetrieval(object):
    
    def __init__(self, entity_kb_path: str):
        
        try:        
            entity_kb = json.load(open(entity_kb_path,'r'))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            raise e # throw again the Exception e after logging

       # initialize the class as you prefer

 try:        
     test = EntityRetrieval('')
 except Exception as e:
        # test is not initialized here, i.e., test is None -> True
        test = EntityRetrieval('correct/path/file.json')
        # or whatever operation to handle the error
 
 # at this point test is not None anymore

The relevant change I did in your code is to call raise e in case of errors to notify the user what happened.
The second try/catch is an example to show a possible response pattern.
In general, you may want to avoid performing long/main operations inside the constructor, but rather delegate these operations to secondary functions.
An example for your case:
class EntityRetrieval(object):
    
    def __init__(self, entity_kb_path: str):
        try:        
            self.entity_kb = json.load(open(entity_kb_path,'r'))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            raise e # throw again the Exception e after logging
    
    def operate_on_file(self):
       # Do here all your ops

 try:        
     test = EntityRetrieval('')
 except Exception as e:
        # test is not initialized here, i.e., test is None -> True
        test = EntityRetrieval('correct/path/file.json')
        # or whatever operation to handle the error
 
 # at this point test is not None anymore
 test.operate_on_file()


You can make the exception handler exit the program with a non-zero status code after producing the logging output:
import sys

try:        
    entity_kb = json.load(open(entity_kb_path,'r'))
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
    sys.exit(1)


Base on @Thecave3 answer, I guess the raise does the sys.exit(1) right?

The raise statement by itself will reraise/propagate the exception currently being handled. And if there is no other exception handler to handle the reraised exception, the program will terminate with a status code of 1, but will also produce a traceback. Since you mention that "I try to throw message error to user when they not pass in correct arguement instead of throw crash", I believe you want to avoid producing the traceback output (which looks like a crash) and instead output the error via logging, in which case you should explicitly exit the program instead of reraising.

hey, does it only work in __main__? I mean .py. As when I test running on notebook, it still throw crash with quite complicated error something like During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred

Anyway thanks for your amazing understanding and explanation.

It should work everywhere. It's hard to tell how you incur another error within your exception handler without seeing your actual code.
